# user indexing for something similar to a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

Need to start off by saying that this is essentially a homework question and it’s really a tough one for me.

From the print output of a dynamic matrix (or anything that can be formatted and printed to be visually similar), I need to use indexing from a user’s input to change values in that “matrix”. It doesn't have to be a matrix, something that can be formatted to be similar would also work.

What makes this problem hard for me is that only un-nested lists, strings, or dictionaries can be used, and importing packages is not allowed. So, list comprehension is out of the question.

One thing I’ve tried so far is to print separate lists and index based on separate lists but I got stuck.

Comment: Separate the problem of how to store/index the data from the problem of how to print it out.  For storing the data, my suggestion is to use a one-dimensional list -- instead of doing `matrix = [[0 for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]` and indexing it as `matrix[i][j]`, do `matrix = [0 for _ in range(cols * rows)]` and index it as `matrix[i * rows + j]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 1D list, take x, y coordinates in user input and convert the y coordinate in terms of x offsets.

For example, say you want to represent a 5x3 array and the user wants the second column (x=2) and third row (y=3). Let's assume our matrix displays with 1,1 being top left corner.

Multiply the y coordinate minus 1 by the width of the matrix to obtain the number of cell offsets in your 1D-list, then further offset by x - 1 (remember, Python lists are 0-based) to position correctly on the x-axis.

Example of matrix with 1D-based indices:

```
0  |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4
5  |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9
10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14
```

Taking the algorithm above:

```
index = (y - 1) * 5 + x - 1 # ((3 - 1) * 5 + 2 - 1) = 11
```

As you can see, 11 is indeed in our matrix the second column and third row, as per the example user inputs.

You can then display the matrix by way of a simple for loop, knowing the size of the matrix and inserting a new line as appropriate.

You may simplify the above a bit if the user is requested to input 0-based indices as well. You will not need to substract 1 from x and y.